# Как защитить программу от копирования?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Делаю одному знакомому программу (лабораторную работу) для университета. Должен буду предоставить ему в том числе и исходники.

Так вот вопрос, что можно придумать, чтобы этот знакомый потом не продал/не отдал эту программу кому-нибудь другому и тот другой ее не сдал с таким же успехом. Навыков у этих людей немного, но, конечно, если просто написать в названии приложения и в верхнем баре фамилию, то это они все таки найдут в коде и запросто поменяют на свою.

Какую защиту и привязку к фамилии человека можно придумать поизощреннее?

Comment: История начала дружбы Стива Джобса со Стивом Возняком ) 1) Сделайте архив  и киньте ему на почту, что соответственно, привяжет ваш код к дате (смысл в том, что это вы послали ему и  раньше его, то есть как-никак ваш код), если в будущем пойдут разбирательсва о делении многомиллионных прибылей с вашей проги, то это будет доказательством в суде 2) в код можно навставлять пасхалок о смысле которых знаете только вы. 3) Пропишите свой @author в самых неожиданных местах. Удачи )

Comment: Кстати, а код на github'e? Тогда можно на почту и не кидать )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если решение не в один коротенький метод, то конкретный почерк четко проявляется в том, как программист делит приложение на методы и классы и в каком порядке они все организованы между собой... И если названия классов и их членов можно еще пофантазировать и придумать другие (или они уже заданы в задаче), то повторить один в один организационную структуру на достаточно объемном материале фактически не реально.

Впрочем, копипастеры могут полениться даже переименовывать, тогда можно попробовать встроить фамилию в названия:

al**b**Rnd im**u**ges el**g**ments co**a**ditional co**e**verted in**n**ternal al**k**Website pa**o**rsing = bugaenko

или посложнее

we**b** to**U**RI pa**g**es im**a**ges el**e**ments co**n**ditioned ma**k**e pr**o**blem

теперь остается только придумать определенные точки чтения (помещения) этой информации

Comment: О какой картинке идет речь?

Comment: web toURI pages images elements conditioned make problem - а это разве не на картинку ссылка?

Comment: это просто перечисление слов, каждая третья буква в которых составляет в итоге фамилию. Это предлагаемый мною автору вопроса - способ скрытно добавить информацию об авторстве кода. (Подправил свой ответ, чтобы лучше было видно)

Comment: Это же гениально! :)

Answer (score 2):

Если требуется предоставить исходники, то о защите можно не говорить. Правда вы можете комментировать ваш код. С помощью аннотации javadoc `@author`. Такие аннотации редко удаляются, особенно если код приносит пользу.